# Two way binding issue for Angular book app example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-databinding

I am an Angular noob trying to work through some examples that I find here and there. I found an interesting example here: http://kirkbushell.me/when-to-use-directives-controllers-or-services-in-angular/ that I have attempted to actually get running. For the most part it works as I would expect.

The service is definitely storing the books and adding the new book as expected, however the list of books output in the view (DOM) is not updating. It would appear that the two-way binding is not set correctly. What might I be doing wrong?

Here is the code that (mostly) works:

```js
var module = angular.module('bookModule', []);

module.service('Book', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var service = {
    books: [
      { title: 'Magician', author: 'Raymond E. Feist' },
      { title: 'The Hobbit', author: 'J.R.R Tolkien' }
    ],

    addBook: function(book) {
      service.books.push(book);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('books.updated');
    }
  };

  return service;
}]);


// Ctrl fn
var ctrl = ['$scope', 'Book', function($scope, Book) {
  $scope.$on('books.updated', function(event) {
    console.log(Book.books);
    $scope.books = Book.books;
  });

  $scope.books = Book.books;
}];
// Initialize the controller
module.controller('books.list', ctrl);


// Directive to handle add book button
module.directive('addBookButton', ['Book', function(Book) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        Book.addBook({title: 'Star Wars', author: 'George Lucas'});
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Book example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="bookModule">
    <h4>Book list</h4>
    <ul ng-controller="books.list">
      <li ng-repeat="book in books">
        Title: {{book.title}} | Author: {{book.author}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button add-book-button>Add book</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event is manually bound, and you are not using angular click directive, Which means you would need to run the digest cycle manually by using `scope.$apply()`.

```
 element.bind('click', function() {
    Book.addBook({title: 'Star Wars', author: 'George Lucas'});
    scope.$apply();
  });
```

```js
var module = angular.module('bookModule', []);

module.service('Book', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var service = {
    books: [
      { title: 'Magician', author: 'Raymond E. Feist' },
      { title: 'The Hobbit', author: 'J.R.R Tolkien' }
    ],

    addBook: function(book) {
      service.books.push(book);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('books.updated');
    }
  };

  return service;
}]);


// Ctrl fn
var ctrl = ['$scope', 'Book', function($scope, Book) {
  $scope.$on('books.updated', function(event) {
    console.log(Book.books);
    $scope.books = Book.books;
  });

  $scope.books = Book.books;
}];
// Initialize the controller
module.controller('books.list', ctrl);


// Directive to handle add book button
module.directive('addBookButton', ['Book', function(Book) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        Book.addBook({title: 'Star Wars', author: 'George Lucas'});
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Book example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="bookModule">
    <h4>Book list</h4>
    <ul ng-controller="books.list">
      <li ng-repeat="book in books">
        Title: {{book.title}} | Author: {{book.author}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button add-book-button>Add book</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To add, it's probably better to just use Angular's ng-click instead of writing your own directive for something like this. Just define the click handler on the controller scope (e.g. $scope.addBook) and hook it up to ng-click (e.g. ng-click="addBook()"). ng-click is bound to an Angular expression, which can be safely evaluated on the scope kind of like eval in vanilla JS (but safe), more info can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: It works! I read about this a little while back in the Angular developer guide too... I just didn't realize this was a case where I would need to use it. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @DerekWebb The thing is i know you are probably doing it as experimental purpose, but it probably does not make much sense to have a directive to just bind a click event.Just as a example your directive can have a template say `<button ng-click="addBook()">Add Book</button>` and just set a directive as ` <add-book-button></add-book-button>`. You should try to avoid using scope.$apply as much as possible, but of course there are many instances where you would need it , but i would suggest you to use them with awareness.. :)

Comment: Ok, I will give the ng-click directive a try as well. Thanks again.